# Raspberry Pi CM4 will not boot at all. Only solid red light, no green activity light

Tags: compute-module-4

I bought a pair of used CM4s, and both seem to have a booting issue (presumably from the eMMC)

Steps to reproduce:

1. I used the CM4 IO board to connect the CM4 via USB from my macOS
   laptop.
2. Next, I used the [`usbboot`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot) repo, and the instructions in the [official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/compute-module.html#compute-module-4) to flash and update the firmware and install the Raspberry Pi OS (tried both 32 and 64 bit).
3. Note that I fit the jumper on nRPI_BOOT as mentioned while flashing.
4. The green activity light blinks rapidly for the above steps, indicating everything to be "seemingly" normal.
5. As expected, Flashing the firmware/bootloader gives me a green screen on a connected HDMI screen.
6. Next, I power off the board, remove the USB connection, remove the jumper, and turn on the power as per the guide.
7. Sadly, I do not see anything on the screen, and the green activity light doesn't come up.

**As a different approach:**

I also tried using `usbboot` to connect the device as `msd` in the GitHub repo instructions and then used the Raspberry PI OS GUI Imager / Installer to flash the OS to the eMMC. This process goes fine, but when I boot the CM4 after the flash, again no activity, nothing on the screen.

I think the eMMC is fine because I can add/remove files with macOS finder (file browser). The data persists between physical disconnections.

I can reproduce this on both my CM4s which are 4 GB RAM and 32 GB eMMC versions. I have also tried different carrier boards with the same results.

What should I do? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no fix!**

It took a while, and I think the CM4s are gone for good. The CM4s are handed over from one buyer to another before ending up with me.

The OTP (One-time programmable) chip has been locked with private keys as a security measure in these steps. These modules are considered "industrial-grade," and only operating systems "signed" by those who used the keys to lock the OTP can boot.

It's a shame that a perfectly OK piece of hardware is just e-waste now.